# How to assign value to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am having menu-bar in that i am using href command how can i add value to link and pass it to next form.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span>Aptitude</span>
            <ul>
                <a href="#">Technical Questions</a>  // a=5
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Technical Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HR Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

if i click technical question link must contain a value as 5 how can i do these.....

Comment: where is the click handler

Comment: you mean you want to add querystring like `something.php?a=5`? also is the value static (that is, is it always 5 for technical question?)

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Perhaps you want to use `$_GET` parameters? In the link, write `index.php?a=value`. In the `index.php` file, this: `<?php echo $_GET['a']; ?>` will output `value`.

Comment: if i click the any one href it must move to other page. it will done if we gave that href code. but i want any of variable(or)value can be carry and display that respective page

Answer (score 1):

You could add a data attribute

```
<a href="#" data-value="5">Technical Questions</a>

//When it is clicked


 $("a").click(function(){
    val = $(this).data('value') // would be 5
    }
```

Comment: how i can get from another page

Comment: @SathishKumar Can you describe the complete flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data attribute here

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <span>Aptitude</span>
            <ul>
                <a href="#" data-elemid="5">Technical Questions</a>  // a=5
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Technical Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HR Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

then in the event handler

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('elemid');
    //do something
})
```